# calling __isset() magic method from empty() function, the magic method returns true but actually it should return false

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

```
class Base
{
  private $firstName;
  private $lastName;

  function setName($firstName, $lastName){
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
  }

  function __isset($property){
    return empty($this->$property);
  }

}

$ob = new Base();
$ob->setName("Hello", "world");

if (empty($ob->firstName)) {
  echo "exist";
} else {
  echo "not exist";
}

// Output: exist
```

I can't understand why the output is `exist`.

The magic method returns true but actually it should return false because I already set the properties.

Comment: I would have thought if you have set the value, `return empty($this->$property);` would return false as the value is not empty.

Comment: Yes it should return false but it returns true

Answer (score 2):

Huh. I have to admit this surprised me a bit as well.

First, lets get the important bits out of the way:

- Using `empty()` and `isset()` can be dangerous and not a great practice. Since these language constructs are not type safe, and coerce values when needed, the results can lead to unexpected bugs. Is generally safer to use more descriptive and type safe options. set the default values to an empty string or even `null`, and compare with that, etc.
- The code in your question does not look very practical, I cannot imagine many use-cases for something like this. More often than not, using magic methods is not a great idea, and using typed properties and/or typed accessors (get/set methods), is. I guess that you are trying to create a parent class where you'll add a some magic logic that some other inheriting classes will take advantage, which is fine... but I don't particularly fancy.
- Your `__isset()` implementation is inherently flawed, since it calls `empty()` on the property. Think about it: when the `empty()` returns `false` (the property is **not** empty), `__isset()` returns `false` as well. The **opposite** of what you'd expect. The fix simple, just return the opposite: `return !empty($this->$property);`.

But, even if you apply that fix your code won't work as expected. And that's the bit that I found slightly surprising....

The thing is that, yes, calling `empty()` on a non-accessible property will call the magic method `__isset()` (if defined).

If `__isset()` returns `false`, `empty()` returns true. If `__isset()` returns `true`, the value from `__get()` is checked to see if it's "falsey" (e.g. empty string, `0`, , `'0'`, `null`, `false` or an empty array would all return `true`). But if the magic `__get()` does not exist, the value is inaccessible and `empty()` returns `true`.

So you'll need to define the magic accessor `__get()` as well. Your class, "fixed", would amount to something [like this](https://3v4l.org/d33sp):

```
class Base
{
  private $firstName;
  private $lastName;

  function setName($firstName, $lastName){
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
  }

  function __isset($property){
    return !empty($this->$property);
  }
  
  function __get($property) {
      return $this->$property;
  }

}

$ob = new Base();
$ob->setName("Hello", "world");

if(empty($ob->firstName)){
  echo "empty";
}
else{
  echo "not empty";
}
```

Note that you require **both** methods. Defining only the magic getter would also fail, since `empty()` calls first the magic `__isset()` and only then (if it returns `true`) the magic getter.

Comment: Can this is not resolved or clear explanation without using get method..

Comment: As explained in the answer, you'll need to define the `__get()` magic method for your approach to work.

Comment: yes i accept your solution but is it any clear explanation why its behave like this.

Comment: It's explained in my answer: `empty()` calls both `__isset()` and `__get()`. It works this way because `empty()` needs to access the values of the property to make the comparison, since it will return `true` for multiple different values (empty string, null, undefined, `false`, `0`, etc). Why does it work this way? Because it's designed this way.

Comment: But empty() also return true if variable is not declared.

Comment: Exactly. I said "undefined" among the values in my previous comment. If `__isset()` returns `false`, `empty()`  returns  `true`. If `__isset()` returns `true`, the value from `__get()` is checked. It's not that hard.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the access modifiers you're using for your fields, both are set to private = cannot access it directly from outside the class, for this you will need the so called getters - [simple explanation](https://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials/access-modifiers-public-private#:%7E:text=private-,Access%20modifiers%3A%20public%20vs,private&text=While%20the%20public%20access%20modifier,that%20is%20outside%20the%20class.):

```
class Base{
  private $firstName;
  private $lastName;

  function setName($firstName, $lastName){
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
  }
  
  function getFirstName (){
      return $this->firstName;
  }

  function getLastName (){
      return $this->lastName;
  }

  function __isset($property){
    return empty($this->$property);
  }

}

$ob = new Base();
$ob->setName("Hello", "world");

if(empty($ob->getFirstName())){
  echo "exist";
}
else{
  echo "not exist";
}
```

Comment: But if we call private property with empty function outside class then it automatically call __isset() method which should return false...